# Adding key-value pairs in a plist file programmatically preserving the existing order of the file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist

Is there any way by which I can add the new key-value pairs to an existing plist file.I also wants to preserve the order of the keys and values in the existing file.I am facing problem in preserving the order if dealing with the plist in dictionaries.Plist file is stored on the disk and all the keys and values are of type "String" except the root which is NSDictionary.

Comment: Store the sorted keys as a separate array.

Comment: On what basis I will sort it and how will I ensure the order will be preserved while rewriting the plist file.Do you mean creating the final XML string manually to keep the order of keys ?

Comment: The semantics of plist files (and key-value storage in general) are just not made for preserving order. 

If you want ordering, it would be better to store an NSArray in the plist instead of the NSDictionary. The NSArray could have a separate dictionary with an entry for the key and value for each key-value pair in the original dictionary. 

May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Sorted key-values do not make any sense at all. You get the value by key, not by key's index.

Comment: @mrueg- Thanks for your suggestion but that is not what I want to do.I need to preserve the order because if the order is not preserved every time you run the "diff" from the "svn" you will get almost whole plist file as modified.I believe I make some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you will need to write your own plist parser and generator. For full flexibility, you’ll need to write it from scratch, not relying on an XML parser, or at least not a general-purpose one.

Comment: @Ahruman-- Thanks.I was also sort of same thought but not sure. To achieve the same I am now moving towards reading the XML string from the plist file via stringWithContentOfFile:..... method of NSString and then appending my key-values(in XML tags) before the </plist> tag and then writing the plist file again from the string made.      Any cons of this approach ?